# Linearising a polynomial using logs

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, linearization

I have been a bit rusty with my natural logs. I want to linearize this polynomial using logs. Does this look correct?

`y = (v-x)/x^2`

`log(y) = log(v - x) - 2log(x)`

`log(y) = log(v) - log(x) - 2log(x)`

`log(y) = log(v) - 3log(x)`

Thus, in `y = mx + c` ==>
`y = log(y); m = -3 ; x = log(x); c = log(v)`

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect.

$log(v-x) \not= log(v)-log(x)$

Further, the function you gave is not a polynomial, and thus cannot be linearized. Linearizing polynomials using logarithms shouldn't be possible as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).